# Java - How to print row numbers on each page?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, awt

I am struggling with printing JTables in my own way. This what I would like to obtain when printing :

```
       Page 1        Page 2        Page 3
    |  1  2  3 |  |  4  5  6 |  |  7  8  9 |
    |1         |  |1         |  |1         |
    |2         |  |2         |  |2         |
    |3         |  |3         |  |3         |

       Page 4        Page 5        Page 6
    |  1  2  3 |  |  4  5  6 |  |  7  8  9 |
    |4         |  |4         |  |4         |
    |5         |  |5         |  |5         |
    |6         |  |6         |  |6         |
```

As you can see, I would like to get tableHeader on each page (which I succeed to get!), and row numbers also, on each page. Does anyone already did something like this ?

This is how my JTable is managed :

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);     // basic JTable
scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(rowTable); // basic JTable with only 1 column
tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();  //
scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(tableHeader);
```

I tried to do something like in `javax.swing.TablePrintable`, i.e. computing each time the clip where to print the table, but without success : the rows numbers print only on the first page. I am kind of desperate, any ideas ?

EDIT : Here's some pictures (too big to be posted here) to show what I obtain for the moment, and what I would like to get :

- Pages 1 and 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGvRT.png

  As you can see, row numbers should be the same on the second page, because it is the left part of the table (and the table's width fit on 2 pages)
- Pages 3 and 4 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/i43aX.png

  Middle part of the table. As you can see the is that now row numbers should not be `1 ... 49` but `50 ... 99`, and they still don't show on left page
- Pages 5 and 6 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6NtA.png

  Bottom part of the table. Row number should be `100` and also appear on the left page.

I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Could you post your printing code?

Comment: It is a bit huge, that's why I haven't posted it. Actually it's very close to what is in `javax.swing.TablePrintable`, on which I try to add printing for row numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954377/how-to-print-row-numbers-of-a-jtable-on-multiple-pages

Comment: Yes possible duplicate, because it was me. This time I tried to make it clearer to explain my issue.

Comment: Could you upload a pic?That will be helpful

Comment: The little scheme is not enough ?

Comment: I am not getting what you mean by printing on each page.Also, what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I edited the question, you can see what I mean now

Comment: @Pigrou your question looks so good but probably you will get a warning from the mods because in your case, the even if the new question is more cleaner you should edit older question, posting a new question with duplicate context is not allowed i was in the same situation and my new question is deleted

Comment: I don't think so because I deleted the other one.

Comment: I succeeded ! I'll upload my answer tomorrow I think, it'll be helpful for beginners like me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest to obtain a solution is to generate something like

```
public class WrapPrintable implements Printable
```

and override

```
 public int print(final Graphics graphics,
               final PageFormat pageFormat,
               int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
```

for the setup for the Paperformat to add additonal header and/or footer space and there write some method like

```
Graphics2D g2d = printGraphics(graphics, pageFormat, pageIndex, format);
```

and the `printGraphics` does your header/footer adjustments, which you need to create by your own... I've done this already once, but the code blows up quite easily, therefore only small fragments.